# Why does alert appear before background changes?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I've been trying stuff lately and got this piece of code in my script:

```
document.body.bgColor = "red";
alert("hello");
```

But in Chrome, the alert dialog pops up first and only after I close it does the background of my body changes. In Firefox, I get the expected behaviour with body background changing to red followed by the popup.

I know we shouldn't rely on alerts and similar browser controls but can anyone tell me if this is happening because the behaviour is not in the standards or if it's because my understanding of synchronous execution of the above code is wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The rendering process has a lifecycle of it's own and does not block the javascript thread. They both work independently.

The solution is to "pause" the JavaScript execution to let the rendering threads catch up. This can be done via a simple `setTimeout` set to `0`

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";

setTimeout(function() {
  alert("hey");
}, 0)
```

Note that `bgColor` has been deprecated since 2003 with the [DOM Level 2 Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-26809268). The current way to set the background color of an element is via `element.style.backgroundColor`.

Comment: Thank you. That helped. One thing that bugs me if this will guarantee the rendering will finish before `alert()` inside `setTimeout()` executes? I mean, for more complicated CSS, is there an event like `onStylesApplied` or something that can hook into the rendering process?

Comment: You can call as many style operations as you like before the `setTimeout` call.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Rendering is not independent from javascript execution. Both are done by the same thread and both block each other. The alert pauses the javascript execution and rendering cannot take place until the javascript is executed completely. setTimeout() puts the alert in the callback queue that causes the alert to happen after the rendering.

Comment: Avoid using a `setTimeout()` of Zero (`0`).  While it did work for me at first, I noticed if I moved my mouse (immediately after clicking the button that initiated the alert) the changes I made to the DOM before calling `alert()` would still not work.  I tested with `10` but ended up going with `100`, as it worked all the time (for what we were doing).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest workaround will be like:

```
document.body.bgColor = "red";
setTimeout(function() {
        window.alert('Hello There!');
    },  10);
```

The timeout value "9" is the minimum in my case, if i use <9, alert appears first.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely can enforce the background color to change before dialog popping up by yielding for a short time before opening the alert thus allowing the browser to repaint.

```
setTimeout(function () { alert("hello"); }, 1);
```