# alert() following display change suspends the change until alert() completes

Tags: javascript

I can work around this by putting the change to display inside setTimeout(), but can someone explain why this happens? Using either of these 2 lines, the change to display isn't completed until the alert() goes away. Thanks for your help.

```
        //$('#' + divId).hide();alert('test');
        document.getElementById(divId).style.display = 'none'; alert('test');
```

the div here is popup window, below. It is later modified and made visible.

```
<div id="reportOptsDiv" style="display: none;">
  <div class="centerDiv">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div id="reportOptsDataDiv">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 15px; text-align: center">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
             onClick="addressBook.saveOptions('rtype', 
       'reportOptsDiv');">Save</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onClick="addressBook.cancelOptions('reportOptsDiv');">Cancel</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div> <!-- end of reportOptsDiv -->
```

Comment: That's just what `alert()` does. There are few reasons to use `alert()` in a real production site.

Comment: Style changes to the DOM don't get rendered immediately. On top of that, an open alert box blocks code execution.  The real question here is, "why are you using `alert`???" :-)

Comment: @Pointy, isn't the question more about why the style change executed before `alert()` doesn't happen before the alert runs?

Comment: @MarkMeyer well I suppose; the point is that `alert()` blocks the thread. I was looking for a duplicate because I'm sure I've seen almost this exact question (not from the same user) but I can't find it.

Comment: @Pointy, maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945552/why-does-alert-appear-before-background-changes

Comment: Yea that's a good one. I have some sort of karmic block when it comes to searching this site.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I couldn't find it elsewhere but it doesn't surprise me that its been asked. Yes, my question is why the change to style doens't get rendered immediately. It's synchronous, single thread, code, no?

Answer (score 0):

The `alert()` blocks the UI thread and hence the display.  So you won't see the changes until the function completes.