# Javascript code executing after all my code should be finished

Tags: javascript

I am trying to debug my javascript code. It is a code of about 2000 lines with several imbricated functions and here are the last lines that are executed:

```
myDiv.innerHTML = "my div content";
alert("finished");
```

I noticed that the content of myDiv is executed only after I have clicked on "OK" to close the alert box.

Before I click on "OK" to close the alert box, the div content is not been updated, eventhough the line with innerHTML is placed before the alert box.

How is this possible?

Comment: Can you make a [mre]?

Comment: are those last lines inside a function? as mentioned before, please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Most likely a bug in your code. Make a minimal repro so we can see the code.

Comment: What is an "imbricated function"? [That word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945552/why-does-alert-appear-before-background-changes) doesn't seem to relate to functions...

Comment: in fact I  had a problem with alerts and confirm dialogs, that they didn't shoot after the code above... so the question may be not that stupid

Comment: @charlietfl - I would certainly have included more detail in the question, but I do think the two lines quoted and the symptom described pretty clearly add up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945552/why-does-alert-appear-before-background-changes).

Comment: Yes these lines are inside a function. Unfortunately I can't produce a reproducible minimal portion of code in a few lines, because many functions call each other (this i what i call "imbricated functions"). To be honest I don't know for sure if there is code executing after the alert but i think it is not the case, i think i will have to find a tracing tool. Thank you very much for the other case about this topic

Comment: by the way, i noticed the firebug console sometimes unexpectedly adds up a log line "> o" at the end of the console logs, i don't know if this could possibly be linked